# python3でBeautifulSoup4を利用して体育館の予約空き状況を確認したいがログインできない

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup

python3でBeautifulSoup4を利用して体育館の予約空き状況を確認したいのですが、ログイン方法が分かりません。手掛かりを教えて頂けないでしょうか？

ここにログインして→https://www.e-shisetsu.e-aichi.jp/user/view/user/mypIndex.html

```html
<form id="childForm" name="layoutChildBody:childForm" method="post" 

enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    autocomplete="off" action="/user/view/user/mypIndex.html">
    <input type="hidden" id="loginJKey" name="layoutChildBody:childForm:loginJKey" value="??????????????">
    <table width="610" cellpadding="0" class="tablebg2" border="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr height="35">
                <td colspan="1" height="35" width="150" class="s-241m" rowspan="1">
                    <div align="center">
                        <br clear="none">
                        <b>利用者ID</b>&nbsp;<font class="font-red">(必須)</font><br clear="none">
                        <br clear="none">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" height="35" class="s-243m" rowspan="1">
                    　<input type="text" id="userid" name="layoutChildBody:childForm:userid" value="?????" title="利用者ID"
                        maxlength="8" size="40">&nbsp;<font class="font-red">(半角数字)</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="35">
                <td colspan="1" height="35" width="150" class="s-241m" rowspan="1">
                    <div align="center">
                        <br clear="none">
                        <b>パスワード</b>&nbsp;<font class="font-red">(必須)</font><br clear="none">
                        <br clear="none">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" height="35" class="s-243m" rowspan="1">
                    　<input type="password" id="passwd" name="layoutChildBody:childForm:passwd" value="?????" title="パスワード"
                        maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" size="40">&nbsp;
                    <span id="isAlphaFlg">
                        <font class="font-red">(半角英数字)</font>
                    </span>

                    <br clear="none"><input id="passchk" type="checkbox">パスワードを表示する
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="layoutChildBody:childForm/view/user/mypIndex.html" value="layoutChildBody:childForm"><span
        style="display: none; position: absolute;"><input type="hidden" name="te-conditions" value="??????"></span>
</form>
```

ここを表示したい→https://www.e-shisetsu.e-aichi.jp/user/view/user/mypMain.html

以下のようなコードを実行してみたのですが、ログイン後のHTMLはいただけませんでした。

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin 


# メールアドレスとパスワードの指定
USER = "???????"
PASS = "?????"

# セッションを開始
session = requests.session()

# ログイン
login_info = {
    "userid":USER,
    "passwd":PASS,
    "back":"/user/view/user/mypIndex.html"
}

# アクション
url_login = "https://www.e-shisetsu.e-aichi.jp/user/view/user/mypMain.html"
res = session.post(url_login, data=login_info)
res.raise_for_status() # エラーならここで例外を発生させる

print(res.text)
```

Comment: 実行されたコードの中には「エラーなら例外を発生させる」とありますが、この部分で何かしらのメッセージ等は表示されていないのでしょうか？対象のページにはログインが必要なのであれば、第三者が気軽に再現するのは難しいと思います。出来る限りの情報を質問文に含めてもらうとアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。

Comment: コピーペーストでよくわかっていないので、「エラーなら～」のコメントもどんなエラーかよく分からないです。やはり、都合よく同じサイトを利用している方はいらっしゃらないですよね。もう少し勉強してみます。回答ありがとうございます。